# Why does my code doesn't print the correct minimum difference?

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to solve [the horse-racing game on Codingame](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/horse-racing-duals). The problem statement is as follows:

> #### Input
>
> Line 1: Number N of horses
>
> The N following lines: the strength Pi of each horse. Pi is an integer.
>
> #### Output
>
> The difference `D` between the two closest strengths. `D` is an integer greater than or equal to 0.

I'm using a `std::set`, and my algorithm is quite easy but for some reason it fails 2/8 of the submission validators. I don't have access to the actual test data, but according to the test names, the code below fails for

- all horses same strength
- horses in disorder

Why does my code fail on that input?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N; cin.ignore();

    set<int> power;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int Pi;
        cin >> Pi; cin.ignore();
        power.insert(Pi);
    }

    int minDiff = 10000000;

    auto i = power.begin();

    while (i != power.end())
    {
        minDiff = min(minDiff, abs(*i - *(++i)));
    }
    
    cout << minDiff << endl;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"I'm kind of stuck on the Horse-racing one,"* Not everyone knows what that "codingame" is, neither do they know what "horse-racing" should be. Show your output and the expected one, or at least add enough of the problem description so that one can actually help you.

Comment: Please don't add "EDIT:" to your post Everyone can see your posts [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41329526/revisions). Just improve the overall quality of your question instead, without adding additional noise.

Comment: And last, but not least, make sure that you include __all__ the code.

Comment: Plase also see [why not to use `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: `*i - *(++i)` is undefined so that program can do anything.

Comment: if power.size() != n you can safely print 0.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, I'll try to apply that to my future posts.

Comment: @user1438832 Yes, that's what I've done to fix my problem.

Comment: I don't really understand why you chose to use a `std::set` in first place - it kills horses with the same strength (which you don't want) and is less efficient than using a plain vector and sorting it after the input (all in all they do have the same algorithmic complexity, but the `set` has bigger constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution fails if any two horses have the same strength:

```
std::set<int> horses;
horses.insert(1);
horses.insert(2);
horses.insert(1);

// your algorithm returns 1, but it should be 0
```

Also, you have undefined behaviour. What happens if `++i` is `power.end()` here?

```
minDiff = std::min(minDiff, abs(*i - *(++i)));
```

Use two iterators instead, and check for the special case where you have only one kind of horse if you want to use `std::set`.

Comment: The special case is not just every horse having the same strength, it's any two horses with the same strength. If three horses have strengths 1, 1, 2, I think the OP needs to output 1-1=0.

Comment: @hvd: actually, that could be an early exit - before inserting the new horse check if it's already there, in that case you can quit immediately printing 0.